# Extract Woocommerce Product Images via scrapy in one column seprated by comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, woocommerce, scrapy

I am creating a data scraper using scrapy. To extract woo-commerce product images I use this command

```
'img': response.css('figure.woocommerce-product-gallery__image a').attrib['href'],
```

Product Link: https://royalprint.pk/product/name-print-superhero-sweatshirt-011/

but it only extract one img url in csv

[image]

I want to scrape Woocommerce Product Images in one column separated by comma.

Please help. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this: `.getall()` returns a list with all results.

```
 response.css('figure.woocommerce-product-gallery__image a::attr("href")').getall()
```

output:

```
['https://royalprint.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/MaroonSweatshirtWonderWoman.jpg', 'https://royalprint.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/G
reySweatshirtWonderWoman.jpg', 'https://royalprint.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/BlueSweatshirtWonderWoman.jpg', 'https://royalprint.pk/
wp-content/uploads/2020/12/BlackSweatshirtWonderWoman.jpg', 'https://royalprint.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/WhiteSweatshirtWonderWoman
.jpg', 'https://royalprint.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/PinkSweatshirtWonderWoman.jpg']
```